# What are these mushrooms growing in my garden?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I live in Southern California. Over the last couple weeks, these two different kinds of mushroom have manifested in my garden. They seem to grow rapidly overnight, only to wither and show up somewhere else a couple days later. For reference, in these images they are about 2-3 inches tall. I'm concerned my neighbor's cat may try to eat them.
[image]
[image]

Comment: The second image is a type of coprinoid https://www.mushroomexpert.com/coprinoid.html There are specialiized mushroom ID groups on FB and Reddit.